# Unable to capture the correct xpath

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath

I need to capture the xpath for the text which contains the ID that is generated dynamically.

Following is code

```
<div id="RequestMessage" class="gMessages"><div class="messages">
    <em>Request ID 12354.<br />
<a href="pAR.do?param_methodKey%3Asubmit.viewResponse=Link">View the response to your  request.</a><br /></em>
```

I am using the following xpath

//*[@id='RequestMessage']/div/em

but webdriver is not capturing the content of the xpath

Please provide the solution.

Comment: I'd start by double-checking whether there is a default namespace in the document. If so, you'll have to use prefixes in your XPath and make sure the XPath processor knows how to resolve them.

Comment: Please have a look on [how to post an SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). Your XPath expression seems appropriate for the snippet you provided; please provide an example that lets us reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would try using css selector and see it that works.

Assuming you are using Java, I have the below code. With the obtained text, you can parse to get the ID.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#RequestMessage")).getText()
```

Answer (score 0):

If ID is generated dynamically then you can't relay on it. I would use `//*[@class='gMessages']//em`. And one more thing is not pretty clear: do you want to get element by its text or text of element. In the first case you need to add `text()` function to your xpath, in the second one -- use WebDriver method `getText()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try following Xpath = `//div[@class='gMessages']//div[@class='messages']//em`
2. If you are using JAVA with selenium. My recommendation is to go with the JAVASCRIPT Executor.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gMessages']//div[@class='messages']//em"));
   JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   String text = js.executeScript(“return document.getElementById(‘your_ID’).innerHTML”).toString();
```